# MathWordProblem : Time and Work

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A can do a job as fast as B and C working together . If B does the job alone in 5 days and C doest it in 6 days . how many day s does it take A to to a job alone

Comment: Welcome to the Math Stack Exchange.  What have you tried?  Do you know anything that could help you solve this problem?

Comment: i take A=B+C => 1/6+1/5 =>11/30 so the A 30 /11 BUT RIGHT answer is 28/11 :( m not getting this how

Comment: Are we assuming that B and C don't co-operate when they work together? Teamwork usually leads to results that are better than the efforts of the individual workers ...

Comment: i have written same as in my book and there is no assumption is written

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct.  The answer key is wrong.

Comment: if it is thank you :)

Comment: A can do a piece of work in 8 days and B in 15 days . how long will it take , A and B together to do the same work ?? 

What i have done is

A=1/8
B=1/15,

A+B=1/8+1/15=> 23/120 

So answer what i got is 120/23 but book's answer is 55/23.....there is something i am doing wrong thats why I am not getting the same answer as mentioned in the book please help ....

Comment: $55/23$ is clearly wrong.  It is barely over two days.  If B were as fast as A they would take four days together.  You are again correct.